# Sinon.test with typescript this is empty object

Tags: typescript, sinon

I am attempting to use sinon within a typescript project and attempting to use its sand boxing features. I have wrapped my tests in the suggested manor and I am attempting to call `this.stub(/stuff/)` as per the documentation.

Unfortunately when I do this, I am getting the following error `TypeError: this.stub is not a function`. As a test I printed `this` to console before the stub and it is an empty object.

Below is an example of the test I am trying to write that is failing. Any suggestions on changes that need to be made to get the sandboxing feature working is greatly appreciated.

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon'
import * as fs from 'fs'
describe("test",()=>
  it("raise error notification if location does not exist", sinon.test(()=>{
      this.stub(fs,"existsSync",(location: string)=> false)
      /* rest of test */
  }))
})
```

Not using the sandbox features and manually restoring the stubs does work for reference. Trying to limit the manual cleanup in the tests if possible.

Comment: share sinon import line else call like `import * as sinon from 'sinon';`

Comment: @Venkatraman I updated the code to include my two include satements as well as the describe block.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer this morning, for anyone who also find this post.

The issue is that you can not use the new ES2015 arrow style function declarations to get access to the correct scope for this with sinon.test. It comes from there 2.0 documentation but the reasons still translates to the 1.0 branch

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon-test/blob/master/README.md#usage